# How to use derive.m function to get central differentioation of f(x)

Tags: matlab

I've a function that can calculate central difference of `f(x)` but I'm basic user of matlab and I can't define f(x) for function I've mentioned.
Can any body help me and define f(x) for this function?

INPUTS are a function f; a value
of h; a specific point a; the number of rows n. The input function f(x)
should be defined as an M-file.

My `f(x) is : S(x) = 10*x-sin(x)`      with  `steps: 0.1`

I want to get `df(x)` near the `piont=pi/6`

I wrote:

```
clc
syms x
derive(10*x-sin(x),0.1,pi/6,14)
```

but I've got this error :

Error using feval
Argument must contain a string or function_handle.

Error in derive (line 7)
D(1,1)=(feval(f,a+h)-feval(f,a-h))/(2*h);

Error in centre(line 2)

========================================

the function `derive.m` is here:

```
function derive(f,h,a,n)
% Approximate the derivative of a function at x = a.
disp(' Derivative table')
disp('______________________________________________')
disp(' i h Di,1 Di,2 Di,3 ... ')
disp('______________________________________________')
D(1,1)=(feval(f,a+h)-feval(f,a-h))/(2*h);
fprintf('%2.0f %8.4f %12.4f\n',1,h,D(1,1));
for i=1:n-1
h=h/2;
D(i+1,1)=(feval(f,a+h)-feval(f,a-h))/(2*h);
fprintf('%2.0f %8.4f %12.4f',i+1,h,D(i+1,1));
for k=1:i
D(i+1,k+1)=D(i+1,k)+(D(i+1,k)-D(i,k))/((4^k)-1);
fprintf('%12.4f',D(i+1,k+1));
end
fprintf('\n');
end
```

Comment: 'must contain a string or function_handle'.  Which part of your input is a string or function handle? (If you don't understand what constitutes a 'string' or 'function handle' in Matlab, re-read the appropriate documentation)

Comment: All thing I've defined are here.Also I defined x in [-pi pi] but this error appeared again! x=-pi:pi/10:pi

Comment: No, you really haven't. Where is there a string or function handle in your code: `derive(10*x-sin(x),0.1,pi/6,14)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`feval` expects a function handle, that is a MatLab function handle. What you provided (`10*x-sin(x)`) is a symbolic expression. 
You can define a function handle as follows:

```
f(x) = 10*x-sin(x);
```

Now `f` is a MatLab function handle, and you can use it as you wish:

```
derive(f,0.1,pi/6,14)
```

***EDIT***

You can also use an [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

```
derive((x)(10*x-sin(x)),0.1,pi/6,14)
```

***END EDIT***

Note, you do not need `syms x`, it defines `x` as a symbol, but in your function definition you use the parameter `x` defined in `f(x)`.

***EDIT***

If you want to use a symbolic function, you can convert it to a MatLab function handle using [`matlabFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I've done above instruction but the error persist!

Comment: Make sure you wrote `f(x) = 10*x-sin(x);` and not `f = 10*x-sin(x);`, also `derive(f,0.1,pi/6,14)` and not `derive(f(x),0.1,pi/6,14)`, and do not call `syms f(x)`. If that doesn't work try `derive(@(x)(10*x-sin(x)),0.1,pi/6,14)`. All this is assuming it is the same error, and not a different one...

Comment: Thanks.The Second method 'derive(@(x)(10*x-sin(x)),0.1,pi/6,14)' worked.Amusing!But why the first instruction didn't work?

Comment: It should have worked, what is written next to `f` in the workspace window?

Comment: Yeah, but, what is written next to `f` in the workspace window?

Comment: The error is :" Error using feval Argument must contain a string or function_handle.

Error in derive (line 7) D(1,1)=(feval(f,a+h)-feval(f,a-h))/(2*h);

Error in centre(line 2)"